# How to solve Excel count of saturday

Tags: excel, excel-formula, weekday, sumproduct

I have a list of dates in MS Excel in column A.
I am using Excel 2016.

[image]

I want to find out how many dates are Sunday and separately Saturday.
I dont know exactly how many rows in sheet so I need to use the whole column.
I am using the following formula:

Count of Saturdays:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A:A)=7))
```

Count of Sundays:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A:A)=1))
```

The same formula is used for Friday only for testing.
Count of Fridays:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A:A)=6))
```

The Friday and Sunday works well as I see, but Saturday returns an icorrect value (it seems to me works on blank values)

Could be is that a WEEKDAY function bug?
Somebody has the same problem?
Any Idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional clause to exclude blanks. And don't use entire column references within `SUMPRODUCT`. Either reformat your column entries as a `Table`, after which your formula would be:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(Table1[Date])=7),--(Table1[Date]<>""))`

else use a construction which determines the last-used cell within that column:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A1:INDEX(A:A,LastRow))=7),--(A1:INDEX(A:A,LastRow)<>""))`

where *LastRow* is defined within *Name Manager* as:

`=MATCH(9^9,Sheet1!$A:$A)`

(Obviously amend *Sheet1* in this definition as required.)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work: =SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9^9,test!$A:$A)))=7),--(A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(9^9,test!$A:$A))<>""))

Answer (score 0):

Considering

Sunday=1
Saturday=6

=SUMPRODUCT(N(WEEKDAY(A:A)={1,6}))